# Can we call arrayFire fft function inside opencl Kernel

Tags: opencl

I want to execute fft on gpu. I am using arrayFire library for that. Since whatever we write inside the opencl kernel will be executing on the gpu(specified device). Can we call fft function inside kernel of opencl.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayFire is a high level library that allows users to compute on GPUs without having to write kernels. ArrayFire provides a high level API for this purpose.

It is NOT possible to call ArrayFire function from inside a kernel as it violates the basic principles of GPU computing.